# The number of polynomials on a finite group

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

A function $f:X\to X$ on a group $X$ is called a *polynomial* if there exist $n\in\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ and elements $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n\in X$ such that $f(x)=a_0xa_1x\cdots xa_n$ for all $x\in X$. The smallest possible number $n$ in this representation is called the *degree* of the polynomial $f$ and is denoted by $\deg(f)$.

Let $\mathrm{Poly}(X)$ be the set of all polynomials on a group $X$.

In fact, $\mathrm{Poly}(X)$ is a submonoid of the monoid $X^X$ of all self-maps of $X$, endowed with the operation of composition of functions.

So, $|\mathrm{Poly}(X)|\le|X^X|=|X|^{|X|}$.

If the group $X$ is commutative, then each polynomial is of the form $f(x)=ax^n$ for some $a\in X$ and $n\in\mathbb N$. This implies that the number of semigroup polynomials on a finite Abelian group $X$ is equal to $|X|\cdot\exp(X)\le |X|^2$ where $\exp(X)=\min\{n\in\mathbb N:\forall x\in X\; (x^n=1)\}$.

> **Question 1.** *Is any reasonable upper bound on the number of polynomials on a finite group $X$?
> For example, is $|\mathrm{Poly}(X)|=o(|X|^{|X|})$?*

Each polynomial $f:X\to X$ on a finite Abelian group $X$ has degree $\deg(f)\le\exp(X)$.

**Question 2.** *Is $\deg(f)\le\exp(X)$ for any polynomial $f:X\to X$ on a finite group $X$?*

**Remark 2.** The affirmative answer to Question 2 would imply that $$|\mathrm{Poly}(X)|\le \sum_{n=1}^{\exp(X)}|X|^{k+1}=\frac{|X|^{\exp(X)+2}-|X|^2}{|X|-1}.$$

**Remark 3.** Finite groups $X$ with $|\mathrm{Poly}(X)|=|X|\cdot\exp(X)$ are characterized in the following theorem.

**Theorem.** A finite group $X$ has $|\mathrm{Poly}(X)|=|X|\cdot\exp(X)$ if and only if $X$ is either commutative or is isomorphic to $Q_8\times A$ for some nontrivial commutative group $A$ of odd order.

*Proof.* To prove the ``if'' part, assume that $X$ is either commutative or $X$ is isomorphic to $Q_8\times A$ for some nontrivial commutative group $A$ of odd order. If $X$ is commutative, then the equality $|\mathrm{Poly}(X)|=|X|\cdot\exp(X)$ is clear.

Now assume that $X=Q_8\times A$ for some nontrivial commutative group $A$ of odd order. [GAP-calculations of Peter Taylor](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/b9e1e62291110b164e091ef7c2f7ead5) show that the group $Q_8$ has exactly 32 polynomials of each degree $k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. This implies that
$$|\mathrm{Poly}(Q_8\times A)|=32\cdot|\mathrm{Poly}(A)|=32\cdot |A|\cdot\exp(A)=4\cdot|X|\cdot\exp(A)=|X|\cdot\exp(X).$$

To prove the ``only if'' part, assume that $X$ is a finite non-commutative group with $|\mathrm{Poly}(X)|=|X|\cdot\exp(X)$.
For every $a\in X$ and $n\in\mathbb N$, consider the polynomial $p_{a,n}(x)=ax^n$. The definition of $\exp(X)$ implies that the set $\mathrm{Pol}(X):=\{p_{a,n}:a\in X,\;1\le n\le \exp(X)\}$ has cardinality $|X|\cdot\exp(X)$ and hence coincides with the set $\mathrm{Poly}(X)$. So, for any $a\in X$ there exists $n\le\exp(X)$ such that $axa^{-1}=x^n$ for all $x\in X$. This implies that every subgroup of $X$ is normal, so $X$ is a [Dedekind group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_group). By the [classical Dedekind result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_group), $X$ is isomorphic to the product $Q_8\times A\times B$ where $A$ is a Abelian group of odd order and $B$ is a Boolean group, i.e., a group of exponent $\exp(B)\le 2$.

If the group $A$ and $B$ is trivial, then $|\mathrm{Poly}(X)|=|\mathrm{Poly}(Q_8)|=128\ne |X|\cdot\exp(X)=32$.

Next, assume that the group $A$ is trivial and $B$ is not trivial. Then $|\mathrm{Poly}(B)|=|\{a,ax:a\in B\}|=2|B|$.
[GAP-calculations of Peter Taylor](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/b9e1e62291110b164e091ef7c2f7ead5) show that the group $Q_8$ has exactly 32 polynomials of each degree $k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. In particular, $Q_8$ has exactly 64 polynomials of even degree and 64 polynomials of odd degree.
This implies that $|\mathrm{Poly}(X)|=64\cdot 2|B|=16|Q_8\times B|=16|X|\ne 4|X|=|X|\cdot\exp(X)=|\mathrm{Poly}(X)|$. This contradiction shows that the group $A$ is nontrivial.

Taking into account that the group $Q_8$ has exactly 32 polynomials of each degree $k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$, we conclude that $$|X|\cdot\exp(X)=|\mathrm{Poly}(X)|=|\mathrm{Poly}(Q_8\times A\times B|=32\times|\mathrm{Poly}(A\times B)|=32\times |A\times B|\times \exp(A\times B)=4\times|Q_8\times A\times B|\times \exp(A\times B)=4\cdot |X|\cdot\exp(A\times B)$$
and hence $\exp(Q_8\times A\times B)=\exp(X)=4\exp(A\times B)$. Since  $\exp(Q_8\times A\times B)=4\exp(A),$ this implies that the Boolean group $B$ is trivial and hence $X=Q_8\times A$.  $\square$

Comment: By my calculations the answer to Q2 is negative: the alternating group $A_4$ has exponent 6 but polynomials of degree 8. FWIW $|\mathrm{Poly}(A_4)| = 36864$.

Comment: For a non-abelian finite simple group $G$, do you see any obstructions to $\mathrm{Poly}(G)=G^G$? Note that $\mathrm{Poly}(G)=G^G$ is equivalent to: for all $h,g\in G$, $\delta_{h,g}\in\mathrm{Poly}(G)$, where $\delta_{h,g}$ maps $h$ to $g$ and all other elements to $1$.

Comment: Furthermore, one can take $\delta_{1,g}(h^{-1}x)$ for $\delta_{h,g}(x)$, and $\{g:\delta_{1,g}\text{ exists}\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, hence $\mathrm{Poly}(G)=G^G$ is equivalent to the existence of $\delta_{1,g}$ for a single $g\ne1$.

Comment: If you have time, can you elaborate a bit on why this sentence is true? "If the group $X$ is commutative, then each polynomial is of the form $f(x)=ax^n$ for some $a \in X$ and $n \in N$

Comment: @Vincent, commute all of the $x$s to the end and $a = a_0 a_1 \cdots a_n$.

Comment: aaah right, I was mixing up multiplication and addition. It is indeed obvious in retrospect. Thanks

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you for calculating $|Poly(A_4)|$. What about $Poly(S_3)$? Is $deg(f)\le 6$ for any polynomial $f$ on $S_3$? The group $S_3$ is the smallest center-free group, so $S_3$ is the first in the line to investigate...

Comment: @YCor Examples of groups with $\delta_{h,g}\in Poly(G)$ have appeared in the study of non-topologizable groups, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0411156.pdf, but all such groups are essentially infinite (finite groups are not interesting for topologizability problems). But maybe finite groups also can be constructed by such methods?

Comment: $A_4$ is the smallest counterexample; the next smallest is $S_3 \times C_3$. [Here's some data on non-Abelian groups up to order 22](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/b9e1e62291110b164e091ef7c2f7ead5). I need to reduce the memory usage before I can handle SL(2, 3) (GAP ID $(24, 3)$).

Comment: This is a special case of an old result of Maurer and Rhodes https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-03/S0002-9939-1965-0175971-0/

Comment: I am always baffled by people who want to exclude $0$ from the natural numbers, but here the first sentence really surprised me; is it meant to be implied that, since a degree cannot be$~0$, constant functions might fail to be called polynomial (as can happen in infinite groups)?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen If we define the degree of a constant map to be zero, then this definition yileds zero information about the group and constant maps. On the other hand, the current definition of the degree is much more informative. For example, the degree of a constant map on an abelian group $X$ is equal to the exponent $\exp(X)$ of the group $X$. So, knowing the degree a a constant map gives the information about the exponent of the group. For nonabelian groups the situation is even more interesting.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen So, calculating the degree of a constant on a group (with the current "positive" definition) is itself an interesting problem. For example, what is the degree of a constant map on the permutation group $S_n$? For $n=3$ it is $\le 4$ as witnessed by the polynomial $xxbxx$ where $b$ is any element of order 2.

Comment: On remark 3: my calculations show two non-commutative groups of order 8 and five of order 16 which have $|\textrm{Poly}(X)| = |X| \exp(X)$.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Poly{Poly}$**Proposition.** If $G$ is a simple non-abelian finite group, then $\Poly(G)=G^G$.

(Edit: this observation appears as the main therorem in [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-03/S0002-9939-1965-0175971-0/) by Maurer and Rhodes, Proc. AMS 1965. See also Theorem 2 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.11956) by Schneider-Thom. Thanks to Benjamin Steinberg for the reference.)

Here is the proof. It uses no machinery.

**Lemma.** There exists $f\in\Poly(G)$ whose support is a singleton.

[Here the support of $f$ means $f^{-1}(G\smallsetminus\{1\})$.]

Indeed, let $f$ have support $\{g\}$. Considering $x\mapsto hf(x)h^{-1}$ we see that all values in a single nontrivial conjugacy class are achieved by polynomials supported by $\{g\}$. By simplicity and taking products, we see that all maps supported by $g$ are definable as polynomials. Moreover after considering $x\mapsto f(gh^{-1}x)$ we obtain all functions supported by $\{h\}$. Since an arbitrary map is product of maps supported by singletons, we obtain the proposition.

Now let us prove the lemma. Let $X$ be a minimal subset among nonempty supports of elements of $\Poly(G)$ ($X$ exists because there exists a polynomial not constant $=1$). Say $X$ is the support of $f$. We have to show that $X$ is a singleton. Fix $g\in X$. So $u(x)=g^{-1}x$ is a polynomial. Also for each $h\in H$, the self-map $v$ defined $v(x)=hf(x)h^{-1}$ is a polynomial. Then $w_h:x\mapsto [u(x),v(x)]$ is a polynomial as well. Its support is contained in $X\smallsetminus\{g\}$. So we obtain a contradiction (a strictly smaller nonempty support), unless $w_h$ is constant equal to $1$ for each choice of $h$. The latter means that for each $x\in X\smallsetminus\{g\}$, the element $g^{-1}x$ commutes with $hf(x)h^{-1}$. That is, the nontrivial element $g^{-1}x$ commutes with a whole nontrivial conjugacy class. But the centralizer of a nontrivial conjugacy class is trivial (it is a normal subgroup, and can't be the whole group because the center is trivial). This is a contradiction unless $X\smallsetminus\{g\}$ is empty, which is precisely what we want. The proof is complete.

---

Remark (after Taras' comment, and also in the above Maurer-Rhodes reference): conversely, for a finite group $G$, the property $\Poly(G)=G^G$ implies that $G$ is simple non-abelian or $|G|\le 2$.

Indeed if $G$ is non-trivial and non-simple, then it has a non-trivial proper normal subgroup $N$, and polynomials have the nontrivial constraint $f(N)\subset f(1)N$.

Otherwise $G=\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$ for $p$ prime or $1$. For such a group, a "polynomial" has the form (using additive notation) $x\mapsto a+bx$ for some $a,b\in\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$ (i.e. is an affine self-map in this ring). There are thus $p^2$ such functions. And $p^2<p^p$ iff $p>2$.

Comment: Very nice answer. Thank you! It seems that your proposition can be converted to a characterization: A finite noncommutative group $X$ is simple if and only if $Poly(X)=X^X$.

Comment: @TarasBanakh you think so? I haven't thought of the case, say, of the direct product of two nonabelian simple groups.

Comment: By the way, why the polynomial $w_h$ is not identity (with empty support)?

Comment: @TarasBanakh this is very explicit in the answer

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks. Concerning the inversion of your proposition: if $G$ contains a nontrivial normal subgroup $H$, then $f[H]\subseteq f(1)H$. So, any function $f:G\to G$ with $f(1)=1$ and $f[H]\not\subseteq H$ is not a polynomial. This can give some upper bounds on $|Poly(X)|$ for nonsimple finite groups.

Comment: This also gives counterexamples to Question 2: by the reasoning in Remark 2, it implies that every nonabelian simple group $G$ has a polynomial of degree $|G|-1$ (which usually exceeds the exponent).

Comment: The proof also provides an upper bound for the degree. If we mean the Laurent degree (allowing $x^{-1}$), it roughly yields the upper bound for the sup of degrees of polynomials provided by this proof is $\sim 2^n$, for $n=|G|$ (degree is roughly multiplied by 2 at each commutator step, and the final step, putting singleton-supported function together, only contributes in $n$). This should be far from optimal. To pass to the degree, replace $x^{-1}$ with $x^{\exp(G)-1}$. This multiplies by $O(\exp(g))$, so remains roughly $\sim 2^n$.

Comment: Every n-ary map on a finite simple non abelian group is a polynomial https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-03/S0002-9939-1965-0175971-0/

Comment: Actually the main theorem of Maurer and Rhodes is that any function $G^n\to G$ is a polynomial in n variables for a simple group. The n-variable result was also essentially rediscovered by the computer scientist David Mix Barrington in order to simulate Boolean circuits with simple groups to show the word problem of a simple non abelian group is complete for the circuit class NC. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_(complexity)

Comment: The first theorem in Maurer-Rhodes applies to subgroups of $G^A$, for $A$ any set. Namely for $G$ finite non abelian simple, every subgroup of $G^A$ containing constants and separating points of $A$, equals $G^A$. This directly applies to the subgroup of $G^G$ generated by $\mathrm{id}_G$ and constants, i.e., $\mathrm{Poly}(G)=G^G$. It is mentioned at the bottom of p2 there ("p553")

Comment: (And actually the corollary for maps $G^n\to G$ on the one hand specifies for $n=1$ to the result on maps $G\to G$, and on the other hand for each given $n$ implies the result for $n=1$: just extend a function on the diagonal to a function $G^n\to G$.)

Answer (score 8):

The fact that $\text{Poly}(G)=G^G$ for simple non-abelian groups extends to multiple variables and this multivariate result also is a consequence of a result in universal algebra. These results can be found in the easily found in the book [A Course in Universal Algebra](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Esnburris/htdocs/UALG/univ-algebra.pdf) by Stanley Burris and H. P. Sankappanavar.

We say that an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is congruence permutable if $\phi\circ\theta=\theta\circ\phi$ whenever $\phi,\theta$ are congruences for $\mathcal{A}$. A variety is congruence permutable if each of its algebras are congruence permutable.

Theorem: A variety $V$ is congruence permutable if and only if there exists a term $t$ that satisfies the identities $t(x,x,y)=t(y,x,x)=y$.

For example, the variety of groups (and also heaps) is congruence permutable since the heap operation $t(x,y,z)=xy^{-1}z$ satisfies the identity $t(x,x,y)=t(y,x,x)=y$.

Suppose that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra with underlying set $A$. Let $\text{Poly}^*(\mathcal{A})\subseteq \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}A^{A^n}$ be the collection of all functions of the form $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mapsto t^{\mathcal{A}}(x_1,\dots,x_n,a_1,\dots,a_m)$ for some term $t$ and $a_1,\dots,a_m\in A$.

We say that $\mathcal{A}$ is functionally complete if $\text{Poly}^*(G)=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}A^{A^n}.$

Theorem: Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a non-trivial finite algebra where the variety $V(\mathcal{A})$ generated by $\mathcal{A}$ is congruence permutable. Then $\mathcal{A}$ is functionally complete if and only if $|\text{Con}(A^2)|=4$.

Corollary: (Maurer and Rhodes) A finite group $G$ is functionally complete if and only if $G$ is non-abelian and simple or $|G|=1$.

Proof: For this result, we only need to prove $\leftarrow$ since the direction $\rightarrow$ is easy. Suppose $G$ is non-abelian and simple. Then we shall show that $G\times G$ has only four normal subgroups, namely $\{e\}^2,\{e\}\times G,G\times\{e\},G\times G$. Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G\times G$.

If $N\subseteq G\times\{e\}$, then since $G$ is simple, we know that $N=G\times\{e\}$ or $N=\{e\}^2$. Similarly, if $N\subseteq\{e\}\times G$, then $N=G\times\{e\}$ or $N=\{e\}^2$.

Suppose now that $N\not\subseteq G\times\{e\}$ and $N\not\subseteq\{e\}\times G$. Then there are $a,b,c,d\in N$ where $(a,b),(c,d)\in N$ but where $a\neq e$ and $d\neq e$. Since $a\neq e$, there is some $r\in G$ with $a\neq rar^{-1}$. In this case $(rar^{-1},b)(a,b)^{-1}=(rar^{-1}a^{-1},e)\in N$. In particular, $N$ contains some element of the form $(\alpha,e)$ where $\alpha\neq e$. Thus, since $N$ is simple, we know that $G\times\{e\}\subseteq N$. By an analogous argument, $\{e\}\times G\subseteq N.$
Therefore, since $(\alpha,\beta)=(\alpha,e)(e,\beta)$ we conclude that $N=G\times G$. But the above theorem and by the fact that the variety of groups is congruence permutable, we conclude that $G$ is functionally complete.

Q.E.D.

The result by Maurer and Rhodes was first mentioned by Benjamin Steinberg in the comments, and the result by Maurer and Rhodes is a generalized of Ycor's answer.

Comment: Based on the time stamps, I think that @‍BenjaminSteinberg's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429619/the-number-of-polynomials-on-a-finite-group#comment1105430_429619) (11 hours ago at time of my comment) came after @‍YCor's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/429635) (15 hours ago).  The generalisation to the $n$-variable case is mentioned in another [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429619/the-number-of-polynomials-on-a-finite-group#comment1105429_429635) of @‍BenjaminSteinberg.

Comment: Note about $G$ of order 2: then every map $G\to G$ is a polynomial (which makes it an exceptional case). But not every map $G^2\to G$ is a polynomial. Indeed writing additively, a "polynomial" is a map $(x,y)\mapsto ax+by+c$, so there are $8$ such maps. But there are $16$ maps from $G^2$ to $G$.