# The highest degree of a polynomial on a finite group

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, polynomials, semigroups-and-monoids

This question is motivated by the comments and the answer to [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/429619/61536).

First let us recall some definitions.

A function $f:X\to X$ on a group $X$ is called a *polynomial* if there exists $n\in\mathbb N=\{1,2,\dots\}$ and elements $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n\in X$ such that $f(x)=a_0xa_1\cdots xa_n$ for all $x\in X$. The smallest possible number $n$ in such a representation is called the *degree* of the polynomial $f$ and denoted by $\deg(f)$.

For a finite abelian group $X$, any polynomial is of the form $f(x)=ax^n$, so the degree of $f$ does not exceed the exponent $\exp(X)=\min\{n\in\mathbb N:\forall x\in X\;\;(x^n=1)\}$ of $X$.

In particular, any constant function on an finite abelian group is a polynomial of degree $\exp(X)$.

On the other hand, the constant function $f:X\to\{1\}\subseteq X$ on any dihendral group $X=D_{2n}$ is a polynomial of degree $\le 4$ as $f(x)=bxxbxx$ where $b$ is a non-central element of order $2$ in $D_{2n}$.

Peter Taylor in his comment to [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/429619/61536) observed that the group $A_4$ has exponent $\exp(A_4)=6$ but possesses a polynomial of degree 8, see [here](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/b9e1e62291110b164e091ef7c2f7ead5) for more information on his calculations.

Emil Jeřábek in his comment to [@YCor's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/429635/61536) observed that every nonabelian simple group $X$ has a polynomial $f:X\to X$ of degree $\deg(f)\ge|X|-1$.

Those facts motivate the following

> **Problem 1.** *Has each finite simple group $X$ a polynomial $f:X\to X$ of degree $\deg(f)=|X|$?*

> **Problem 2.** *Is $\deg(f)\le|X|$ for any polynomial $f:X\to X$ on a finite group $X$?*

**Remark.** It is easy to see that each polynomial $f:X\to X$ on a finite group $X$ has $\deg(f)\le|X|^{|X|-1}$. @YCor in the comment to [his answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/429635/61536) has an exponential upper bound for degrees of polynomials on finite simple groups, but this upper bound (being exponential) is quite far from the hypothetic upper bound $\deg(f)\le|X|$ in the problem.

**Added in Edit.** Benjamin Steinberg in his comment suggested to look at  Theorem 2 of [this preprint of Schneider and Thom](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.11956.pdf) whose proof implies the upper bound $2|X|^3\exp(X)cn(X)$ for the largest degree of a polynomial on a finite simple group $X$. The number $cn(X)$ is defined as the smallest number $m$ such that for any normal subset $S\ne\{1\}$ in a finite simple group $X$ we have $S^m=X$. By a [result of Liebeck and Shalev](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3062101), $cn(X)=O(\ln(|X|))$, which yields the upper bound $O(|X|^3\exp(|X|)\ln(|X|))$ for the largest degree of a polynomial on a finite simple group $X$.

Comment: If such a bound is true for nonabelian simple groups then there is very little redundancy in representing functions by polynomial expressions (since every function is a polynomial and the number of functions is $|X|^{|X|}$). Is that plausible?

Comment: @WillSawin Maybe you are right: since the exponent of a finite simple group is rather small comparing to the cardinality of the group there are many polynomial representations of the constant unit function, so many polynomial representations of a given function. On the other hand, there are $\frac{|X|^{|X|+2}-|X|^2}{|X|-1}$ polynomials of degree $\le|X|$, which is almost $|X|$ times larger than the number $|X|^{|X|}$ of all functions.

Comment: I asked it as a question for a reason because I wasn't sure if I thought it was plausible. I note that it's probably more natural to let constant functions have degree $0$ in which case the lower bound is $|X|-1$ in both finite simple and abelian cyclic cases, which is suggestive that $|X|-1$ is the right conjecture in this version, but then $|X|-1$ really is somewhat implausibly (but not entirely implausibly) tight.

Comment: I'd actually call this the semigroup degree, and allow $x^{-1}$ in the group degree. For finite groups $G$ the semigroup degree is at most $(\exp(G)-1)$ times the group degree. I'd like an explicit group polynomial that vanishes for, say, $\mathrm{Alt}_5$.

Comment: (BTW in the linked answer I claimed "roughly" $\le 2^n$ for $n=|G|$. I didn't claim $O(2^n)$, since the proof more likely yields $O(n2^n)$ or $O(n^22^n)$, I didn't carefully check, since it's unimportant — there is certainly a much better upper bound.)

Comment: @YCor You are right. Your upper bound is a bit higher than $2^n$ because of the commutators, which has negative powers that should be rewritten using larger positive powers, so this yield some additions to the upper bound. So, I corrected my Remark using less explicit expressions.

Comment: This is studied where inverses are allowed in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.11956.pdf. See theorem 2

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thank you for the link. Theorem 2 in the paper of Schneider and Thom yields the upper bound $O(|X|^3 cn(X))$ for the largest degree of a polynomial with positive and negative powers. If we rewrite those polynomials using only positive powers, and apply the upper bound $cn(X)=O(\ln(|X|)$ of Liebeck and Shalev (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.11956.pdf) for $cn(X)$, we obtain the upper bound $O(|X|^4\ln(|X|))$ for the largest degree of a polynomial on a finite simple group, which is still larger than the upper bound $|X|$ in the problem.